# Update multiple columns using variable as column with concatination inside while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a situation where i want to update multiple columns but i don't want to write so many `UPDATE` lines.

Is it possible to use a variable as column name ? , then that variable will change inside `WHILE` loop, consider the following sample below.

**EX:**

Table: Test

```
Column01
Column02
Column03
Column04
Column05
Column06
Column07
Column08
Column09
Column10

DECLARE @ctr INT = 01
WHILE @ctr <= 10
    BEGIN
         -->> Is it possible to perform concatenation here to manipulate column name ?
         UPDATE Test SET (Column + @ctr) = SomeValueHere... -->> assume that @ctr = 01
    END
SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
```

The query every loop will look something:

```
         -->> The first loop will look something like
         UPDATE Test SET Column01 = SomeValueHere...

         -->> The second loop will look something like
         UPDATE Test SET Column02 = SomeValueHere...
```

How can i achieve this ?
Thank in advance.

Comment: This is probably a bad and inneficient way of doing it. You can use UPDATE Test SET Column01 = XXX, Col2 = YYY ...

Comment: Just write out the column names that you want to update. I would imagine that you have spent thinking about this, and then writing this question, you could have written out the columns, performed your update, then carried on with your day. You can use the system catalog views to make your life easier, e.g. use `SELECT Name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourTableName', 'U');`, but I would be very hesitant to automate the production of an update script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @script NVARCHAR(max)
SET @script = 'UPDATE Test SET (Column' + @ctr + ') = ' [whatever]
EXECUTE (@script)
```